# MySQL autoincrement value increases even when insertion fails due to error

Tags: mysql, sql, auto-increment

As I receive data from the user, I validate the format of the input every time (PHP). The only thing I can't validate (or I wouldn't want to) is the constraint (for example foreign key) violation. I let the DML to raise and error and the database driver to throw an exception. After catching it I just print out some error message by MySQL's error code.

The problem is, even when insertion fails, I see that the `autoincrement` sequence still grows, increases. How can I prevent that?

Comment: Ideally you don't trigger the `INSERT` at DB-level at all if the data is invalid. Reason being whenever the next ID is selected from a DB sequence the sequence automatically gets to the next value, i.e. we see the "autoincrement" grow. But that is the correct (and expected) behaviour. Hence I suggest to check/clean your data before hitting the DB. (This is just a comment not an answer).

Comment: Does a couple of foreign key constraint check for each table with SFW queries from the PHP entity faster, than just hitting the database once and letting it to deal with the violation? I mean, when you have 5 constraints to check, it would mean 5 `SELECT` and test from the PHP entity. (Smells like an overhead for me.)

Comment: I agree about the "overhead" caused by additional queries. However since they are FKs (i.e. ID fields) they should run against indexes (usually automatically created for FK constraints/IDs), which in some cases (depending on traffic/usage/index-size) are simply kept in memory. Depends on your specific situation. Personally, when I use ORMs I fetch the related object (via FK, i.e. index lookup) from DB before inserting the new/updated related entity, therefore never having to deal with sequence-generated IDs themselves.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

That is how auto increment values and sequences work. When a value is used, it is not reclaimed if the transaction fails, and the transaction is rolled back.

Since you are using auto increment values, the actual value does not matter so the spaces should not be a problem, apart from the aesthetics of having missing numbers.

Comment: So there is no way to prevent it, you say. As I've discovered just lately, the sequence won't shift when there's a foreign key violation, but it will, when the `INSERT` fails due to `NOT NULL` error. Maybe the sequence shifts just before that part. Would like to know, how MySQL evaluates these statements on DML engine level.

Comment: Yes there is none, but since the autoincrements are meant to be unique and increasing, you do not need to worry about that. I know the gaps look funny when you look at the data, but they just do not need to make sense

Comment: Missing numbers in auto-increment means lesser capacity in table to accommodate max number of records. Question is why should not a failed transaction trigger (implicit) roll-back of primary-key value? Why primary-key value should be lost ? Why not recovering to original state should not at least be an option with user ?

Comment: Then use a larger data value, if you have too many rollbacks then there is probably an issue within your architecture and design that needs to be handled

Comment: I use unsigned BIGINT's for all my SQL id's/keys... if you need more than an unsigned BIGINT 18,446,744,073,709,551,615 (2^64-1) id's then wow... I would LOVE to see your server.  :)  Even unsigned INT's are very large... 4,294,967,295.  I think you and I would be long gone before a database needed more than a unsigned BIGINT.  

I understand where you are coming from.  I saw the gaps in my DB and it annoyed me.  I knew what was happening, came here to see if you could turn it off... but, like everyone says... ignore it... just use bigger numbers for your keys.

Answer (score 1):

We should do check if there an error before insert it, by using Stored Procedure and create an Raise Application Error for every error condition, so that our auto_increment will never increase when there is an error in insert proses. It because when an error occur inside the stored procedure you can set condition when the insert proces can be execute. When error accout set a signal state = 1 or something and when signal state == 1 end end the Stored Procedure and do not execute insert stmt. It something like that.

And the second option is to reset the auto_increment, when error occur.

```
ALTER TABLE table_name AUTO_INCREMENT = ?
```

But we need to know the last_id for set the auto_increment, event you doesn't need to know the last_id value has auto_increment by setting equal to 1, MySQL will set the next auto_increment equal to max key of record + 1.

Lets say in your database max id is 7, then you trying to insert two new record but those both return an error then make the auto_increment will increase and turn into 10.
Then you do **ALTER TABLE table_name AUTO_INCREMENT = 1**; The auto_increment will back into 8.

Those both are the way to control auto_increment value when error acour and of course before insert into database on application layer we should handle it in validation step so when insert into database there should be not any error, if we carefully handle this in application layer.

Answer (score 0):

You may have to set innodb_autoinc_lock_mode to 0 or 2.