# Why MySQL should not recover primary-key from a failed / rolled-back transaction?

Tags: mysql, transactions, rollback

On the link;
[MySQL autoincrement value increases even when insertion fails due to error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10108593/mysql-autoincrement-value-increases-even-when-insertion-fails-due-to-error)

.. it is mentioned that "Missing few auto-increment values (gaps in sequence) due to failed / rolled-back transaction is just fine"

BUT ...
Missing numbers in auto-increment (primary key) means lesser capacity in table to accommodate max number of records.

My Questions:

1) Why should not a failed transaction trigger (an implicit) roll-back of the  primary-key value? not persisted yet;not permanent yet. In other words, why it is fine to miss a primary-key value on failed (or, rolled back) transaction?

2) Why not recovering to original state should at least be an "option" with MySQL user; developer ?

Comment: You will have other problems before you run out of auto generated numbers.

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple transactions going on at the same time against same table and the ones getting earlier autoincrement value gets rolled back, you are bound to have gaps in the autoincrement, otherwise the autoincrement handling would be far more complex.

Do not worry about the running out of autoincrement values. It will not happen ([see maximimum integer value of 2^64-1](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/integer-types.html)).